# How to manage large/complex NoSQL queries in code, can we make it generic?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, generics, mongoose

I've been using mongoose in node js for interacting with mongodb, now for every search/update/delete operation I'll have to write a JSON such as,

```
Model.find({
    "$and": [
        { "name": name },
        {
            "start": { 
                "$or": [
                    { "$exists": false },
                    { "$gte": start } 
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "stop": { 
                "$or": [
                    { "$exists": false },
                    { "$gte": stop } 
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}).exec(callback);
```

Now everytime I've to get any such objects I'll have to make a method which makes such query, or even if I make a generic method it'll have limited parameters as input unless I pass a JSON which again makes almost same amount of code.

So what is best practice for managing such queries in code ?

Comment: you can use tools like : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-querybuilder, or write one yourself

Comment: Thanks that could be used. :)